# How many queues can be created in ActiveMQ?

Tags: activemq-classic

How many queues can be created in ActiveMQ? Is there any limitation in ActiveMQ 5.14?

I have a Java application which need to create 1 queue per customer. My concern is what will affect if I create the queue more than 1,000 queues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no arbitrary limit on the number of queues. The only limitation is the resources available to the JVM as each new queue will consume heap memory not just for the messages in the queue but for the queue's own data-structures.

I recommend you move forward with creating however many queues you need and if you run into trouble make careful observations and ask new questions if you need to.

Comment: how to know how many consumer counts we can add up in a dedicated queue created for activemq server?

Comment: Every use-case is different. There is no arbitrary limit on the number of consumers a queue can support. You'll just need to conduct experiments to see how many you can add given your resource and performance constraints.